# How to use same function (from module) on all columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I'm trying to use same function on all columns (except 0) on pandas DataFrame. In my DataFrame i have a lot of columns, and if try to write the same code it will take years for me.

Result from the code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ltrv.jpg

CSV file: http://www.sharecsv.com/s/23d52aa16dda504c3c20a8f37ea5daeb/file_1.csv

## Note: I am a beginner in programming (coding), so please simpler answers.

I write some code, and you can find it below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import peakdetect as pkd

# Importing the Data:

df = pd.read_csv("file_1.csv")

# Min & Max
# Loop (this is for small number of columns)

_mx1, _mn1 = pkd.peakdetect(df["y1"], df["x"], 3, 0.20)

_xm1 = [p[0] for p in _mx1]
_ym1 = [p[1] for p in _mx1]
_xn1 = [p[0] for p in _mn1]
_yn1 = [p[1] for p in _mn1]

_mx2, _mn2 = pkd.peakdetect(df["y2"], df["x"], 3, 0.20)

_xm2 = [p[0] for p in _mx2]
_ym2 = [p[1] for p in _mx2]
_xn2 = [p[0] for p in _mn2]
_yn2 = [p[1] for p in _mn2]

_mx3, _mn3 = pkd.peakdetect(df["y3"], df["x"], 3, 0.20)

_xm3 = [p[0] for p in _mx3]
_ym3 = [p[1] for p in _mx3]
_xn3 = [p[0] for p in _mn3]
_yn3 = [p[1] for p in _mn3]

_mx4, _mn4 = pkd.peakdetect(df["y4"], df["x"], 3, 0.20)

_xm4 = [p[0] for p in _mx4]
_ym4 = [p[1] for p in _mx4]
_xn4 = [p[0] for p in _mn4]
_yn4 = [p[1] for p in _mn4]

d_y_mx = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(_ym1, _ym2, _ym3, _ym4)))
```

Comment: check out `applymap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def func(x):
    _mx4, _mn4 = pkd.peakdetect(x, df["x"], 3, 0.20)
    _ym4 = [p[1] for p in _mx4]
    return _ym4

d_y_mx = df[df.columns[1:]].apply(func)
```

It should already be a dataframe. But to change it to a dataframe, you can do either:

```
d_y_mx = pd.DataFrame(d_y_mx)
```

or as suggested by LazyCoder:

```
d_y_mx = d_y_mx.to_frame()
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine, but in the end the d_y_mx is saved as Series and i need it as dataframe.

Comment: ```.to_frame()``` to the rescue buddy!

Comment: @phoenix_dj see my update. Please accept the answer if your problem was resolved!

Comment: @Akaisteph7  I tried both solutions and the first one:  "d_y_mx = pd.DataFrame(d_y_mx)", changes only the type from Series to dataframe, but doesn't change anything inside. For the second solution "d_y_mx = d_y_mx.to_frame()" it shows this error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_frame'.

Also, i have a sub-question: Is it possible in the new dataframe d_y_mx to retain the same column names as the original dataframe df without typing them manually like: df.columns = [....] .

Thanks for your answers and help!

Comment: I found solution for changing the series lists to dataframe: 

"d_y_mx = df[df.columns[1:]].apply(func)
d_y_mx = pd.DataFrame.from_items(zip(d_y_mx.index, d_y_mx.values))"

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. I have skipped other variables as I assumed that only the d_y_mx is the one you're after.

```py
_ym = [] #Initialize to be empty list for now.
for y in ('y1','y2','y3','y4'): # Loop over all the y combinations
    _mx,_mn = pkd.peakdetect(df[y], df["x"], 3, 0.20) # Run what I assume is some form of min/max getter.
    _ym.append([p[1] for p in _mx])# append to the list.
d_y_mx = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(tuple(_ym))) # Extract the required data.
```